# dynamic in c# without IDynamicMetaObject?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, clr

> An object can provide its binding semantics by implementing
>   IDynamicMetaObject Provider—or more easily by subclassing
>   DynamicObject, which provides a default implementation of this
>   interface.

[source](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449334192/chapter-20dot-dynamic-programming/implementing_dynamic_objects)

I never implemented this interface nor class and always been able to execute things dynamically:

```
public class aa
    {
        public void bbb()
        {  }
    }

dynamic a = new aa().bbb();
```

so what do they mean by this quote ?

*im trying to understand when should i need to use IDynamicMetaObject or the DynamicObject inheritance*

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in the code you posted... the call to bbb is resolved statically

Comment: @ThomasLevesque isnt dynamic reolves at runtimne ? , i could elminitate the function from the class - and still it compiles.... (checked) so its on runtime

Comment: Yes, if you call something on `a`, but it's not what you're doing here.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque i know,  still i dont think the call to bbb is resolved staticly.

Comment: It is correct that the references would be resolved dynamically, but to what end?

Comment: @jamietre it just an example.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, in the code you posted, yes, it is resolved statically. At the call site, the compiler knows that the method is called on an instance of `aa`. The assignment to dynamic occurs only after the call. And anyway, this code wouldn't compile: `bbb` returns void, so you can't assign it to a variable

Comment: @Thomas just to be perfectly accurate it woudln't compile even if bbb returned something, since bbb is not a static method. He would need `(new aa()).bbb()`. At the same time it is perfectly possible to misuse `dynamic` in the way I think he was trying to, e.g. `dynamic a = new aa(); dynamic b = a.bbb();` will compile just fine. And not run of course.

Comment: @jamietre, `new aa().bbb()` is syntactically correct, there is no need for parens...

Comment: Oh hey you're right. I feel as if that has not worked for me in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dynamic` keyword causes references to an object to be late-bound and only resolved at runtime. Usually, the reason for this is because you are using an `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` implementer, which allows your code to decide how to treat the run-time property resolution. That is, you may want to add and remove properties at runtime (typically implemented as a dictionary, like `ExpandoObject`).

What your example code is doing is just preventing compile-type type checking. In fact it's worse than doing nothing, because if you wrote code that accessed a nonexistent property or method of your class, it would still compile, but of course crash at runtime. I can't think of many good reasons to refer to concrete classes with `dynamic` (expect for squishy typecasting or duck-typing, but we usually use interfaces for stuff like this in C#!)

Example implementation of a dynamic object that inherits `DynamicObject` from one of my own projects:

https://github.com/jamietre/IQObjectMapper/blob/master/source/IQObjectMapper/IQDynamicObject.cs

(It makes one call to a factory method that returns a new dictionary with options, all you need to do to make this non-dependent is change the constructor from:

```
InnerDict = ObjectMapper.MapperCache.GetDictionary<object>(Options);
```

to:

```
InnerDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
```

and get rid of a couple conditons that check options

Comment: im trying to understand when should i need to use IDynamicMetaObject  or the DynamicObject inheritance

Comment: `DynamicObject` is just a pre-rolled thing that implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. If you want to make your own `ExpandoObject`-like implemenation, it's easiest to inherit from `DynamicObject` since it does the nitty gritty work for you. There are good reasons to do this, e.g. the .NET `ExpandoObject` will not let you try to read non-existent properties.  You can build your own from scratch, there's articles about how to do it, but most of the time inheriting `DynamicObject` is just fine.

Comment: ive been using quite a lot with `ExpandoObject`.. but besides expando , `im trying to understand when should i need to use IDynamicMetaObject or the DynamicObject inheritance`

Comment: `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` is an interface. It means "this object implements the methods needed for run-time property resolution." Both `ExpandoObject` and `DynamicObject` implement it. It's not a choice, you HAVE to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. The question is, will you build your object from scratch, or will you inherit `DynamicObject` and use it's pre-built functionality?

Comment: Oh and you can't inherit `ExpandoObject`, it's sealed. But in practice writing a simple class that inherits `DynamicObject` and uses a `Dictionary<string,object>` to store the data is identical to `ExpandoObject`. Not sure why they didn't just let us inherit that too, but the code to build an `ExpandoObject` equivalent from `DynamicObject` is trivial.

Comment: I added a link to an example from one of my projects that does exactly this.

Comment: What the OP is using the `dynamic` keyword for is actually what `var` does. Let's the compiler figure out the type that is statically referred to without having to tell it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to give "pithy" answers like this, because its not very imformative, but this really is a case of "if you needed it, you would know."

It is very rare that you would need to *implement* a dynamic object in an application, or even most library code. The interface is meant for people implementing classes that can *only* be used as dynamic objects; for example, if you wanted to implement Javascript-like behavior on your object. You can call any property or method you want on such an object, and it will compile. It's up to your implementation at run-time to figure out whether a given call works or not.

A totally pointless but descriptive example would be a class that decides which properties are valid based on the day of the week:

```
public class WeekendObject : DynamicObject
{
  Dictionary<string, object> propertybag = new Dictionary<string, object>();      

  public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
  {
    if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
      if (name.StartsWith("Sunday"))
      {
        return propertybag.TryGetValue(name, out result);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (!name.StartsWith("Sunday"))
      {
        return propertybag.TryGetValue(name, out result);
      }
    }
  }

  public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
  {
    if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
      if (name.StartsWith("Sunday"))
      {
        propertybag[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (!name.StartsWith("Sunday"))
      {
        propertybag[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```